# Using .bat file and task scheduler for execution of .vbs file

Tags: excel, vba, windows, scheduled-tasks

My Below Code is Running properly.

1.) Can someone help me know how to use task scheduler to schedule this VBS file?

2.) Also i would like to understand writing the .bat file for the execution of this script.

See the code below:

```
    Macro1
Private Sub Macro1()
Set objExcel  = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\kursekar\Documents\Work\Dailytasks\January\ReferralStrApp\StdztnRefRepTrial.xlsx")
objExcel.Visible = True
Dim Conn
Dim RS
Dim SQL
SQL = "WITH cte_REFERRALS_REPORTS(referralnum, refer_from, refer_from_name, refer_from_id, refer_to, refer_to_name, refer_to_id) AS (SELECT referralnum, refer_from, CASE WHEN refer_from_id = 'R' THEN RdicF.refname WHEN refer_from_id = 'P' THEN PdicF.provname END AS refer_from_name, refer_from_id, refer_to, "
SQL = SQL & "CASE WHEN refer_to_id = 'R' THEN RdicT.refname WHEN refer_to_id = 'P' THEN PdicT.provname END AS refer_to_name, refer_to_id FROM referral_t r Left Join refcode_t RdicF ON  r.refer_from = CASE WHEN r.refer_from_id='R' THEN RdicF.refcode ELSE NULL END Left Join refcode_t RdicT ON  r.refer_to = CASE WHEN r.refer_to_id = 'R' THEN RdicT.refcode ELSE NULL END "
SQL = SQL & "Left Join provcode_t PdicF ON r.refer_from  = CASE WHEN r.refer_from_id = 'P' THEN PdicF.provcode ELSE NULL END Left Join provcode_t PdicT ON r.refer_to = CASE WHEN r.refer_to_id = 'P' THEN PdicT.provcode ELSE NULL END ) SELECT chgslipno , a.acctno, patfname, patlname, appt_date, a.enccode, pr.provname "
SQL = SQL & ",a.provcode, rfc.refname, a.refcode, r1.refer_from as r1_ref_from, r1.refer_from_id as r1_ref_from_id, r1.refer_from_name as r1_ref_from_name, a.referral1 as r1_refnum, r2.refer_from as r2_ref_from, r2.refer_from_id as r2_ref_from_id, r2.refer_from_name as r2_ref_from_name,a.referral2, prgrc.provgrpdesc,s.specdesc, a.prov_dept, pos.posdesc,pr.cred "
SQL = SQL & "FROM apptmt_t a Left JOIN patdemo_t p ON a.acctno = p.acctno LEFT JOIN provcode_t pr ON pr.provcode = a.provcode LEFT JOIN refcode_t rfc ON a.refcode = rfc.refcode LEFT JOIN (SELECT*FROM cte_REFERRALS_REPORTS) r1 ON a.referral1 = r1.referralnum LEFT JOIN (SELECT*FROM cte_REFERRALS_REPORTS) r2 "
SQL = SQL & "on a.referral2 = r2.referralnum LEFT JOIN provgrpprov_t prgrpr on a.provcode = prgrpr.provcode LEFT JOIN provgrpcode_t prgrc on prgrpr.provgrpcode = prgrc.provgrpcode LEFT JOIN specialty_t s on pr.speccode = s.speccode LEFT JOIN poscode_t pos on a.poscode = pos.poscode "
SQL = SQL & "WHERE UPPER(a.enccode) in ('CON','APE','COB','CONZ','HAC','HFUI','MMN','NCG','NCHF','NCPF','NHFU','NMC','NOB','NP','NP15','NPE','NPI','NPOV','NPS','NPSV','NPV','OVN','IMC','NP30') AND UPPER(a.appt_status)='ARR' AND appt_date >= '2017-01-01' "
SQL = SQL & "ORDER BY a.acctno"
Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password='25LaurelRoad';User ID='CPSMDIT\kursekar';Data Source='analyzer';Initial Catalog='analyzer_str';Integrated Security=SSPI; Persist Security Info=True;"
Set RS = Conn.Execute(SQL)
Set Sheet = objWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Sheet.Activate
Dim R
R = 2
While RS.EOF = False
  Sheet.Cells(R, 1).Value = RS.Fields(0)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 2).Value = RS.Fields(1)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 3).Value = RS.Fields(2)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 4).Value = RS.Fields(3)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 5).Value = RS.Fields(4)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 6).Value = RS.Fields(5)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 7).Value = RS.Fields(6)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 8).Value = RS.Fields(7)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 9).Value = RS.Fields(8)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 10).Value = RS.Fields(9)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 11).Value = RS.Fields(10)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 12).Value = RS.Fields(11)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 13).Value = RS.Fields(12)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 14).Value = RS.Fields(13)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 15).Value = RS.Fields(14)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 16).Value = RS.Fields(15)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 17).Value = RS.Fields(16)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 18).Value = RS.Fields(17)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 19).Value = RS.Fields(18)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 20).Value = RS.Fields(19)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 21).Value = RS.Fields(20)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 22).Value = RS.Fields(21)
  Sheet.Cells(R, 23).Value = RS.Fields(22)
  RS.MoveNext
  R = R + 1
Wend
RS.Close
Conn.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Release memory
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing
ActiveWorkbook.Save
'objWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\\Users\kursekar\Documents\Work\Dailytasks\January\ReferralStrApp\StdztnRefRepTrial.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
objWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Workbooks.Close
objExcel.Quit
Workbooks.Close
Set objExcel = Nothing
MsgBox ("Saved")
End Sub
```

Thanks is advance guys !!! Please feel free for inputs. i am totally new to VB.

Comment: Event handlers won't fire in a closed workbook. Your solution would need to go outside of just Excel.

Comment: Like what?? Any material to begin with that I can refer or simple explanations is appreciated. I am pulling data from a SQL server.

Comment: What's the idea of updating a *closed* Excel sheet? Why not update it when it is opened? And be carefull: If you use `CopyFromRecordset`, clear your sheet first, else you will have some old records at the end if the SQL returns less rows than last time

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible to use `OnTime` to run a macro in a closed workbook. **You just need to ensure that Excel itself isn't closed completely** (as I assume that wipes the schedule). If the macro is in a closed workbook, Excel will re-open the workbook in order to run it.

Comment: @CLR That makes sense since it is `Application.OnTime` rather than `Workbook.OnTime`, but since OP wants things to fire even if Excel is closed, the distinction doesn't really matter.

Comment: @CLR I want this report to be sent to client every morning and i dont wish to spend time doing everything manually. Also can you please explain where I should use "CopyFromRecordset" Thank you

Comment: Assuming you're running SQL Server Standard (or Enterprise), consider setting up SQL Server Reporting Services and recreating the report on SSRS. Then you can schedule the report within the SSRS portal and have it emailed automatically anywhere, as an Excel workbook attachment if you lke. No need for any VBA, Excel, or Task Scheduler. More of an IT job though (SSRS reports are done in Visual Studio)

Comment: I have never used SSRS. but yes I am fairly well at SQL and this is a SQL Server. I am having graphs and trends to in this excel file after data is imported. Will that be too done in SSRS? Any link for articles is appreciated !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to follow several steps do this to achieve your goal. 
First, you set up your function in your `Workbook_Open()`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Call StandardizationReferralReports
End Sub
```

Then you create a Task Scheduler that opens your excel file at a specific given time. 
You have two way to do this:

1. You **manually** create a new `Task` in Windows `Task Scheduler`. You can open it by :

   - <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> -> `taskschd.msc`

[image]

2. You use a `VBA Macro` to **automatically** create a task routine, following [Microsoft Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/time-trigger-example--scripting-)

Here's a sample code that you can use to start:

```
 Sub createTask()
    '------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' This sample schedules a task to start notepad.exe 30 seconds
    ' from the time the task is registered.
    '------------------------------------------------------------------

    ' A constant that specifies a time-based trigger.
    Const TriggerTypeTime = 1
    ' A constant that specifies an executable action.
    Const ActionTypeExec = 0


    '********************************************************
    ' Create the TaskService object.
    Set service = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
    Call service.Connect

    '********************************************************
    ' Get a folder to create a task definition in.
    Dim rootFolder
    Set rootFolder = service.GetFolder("\")

    ' The taskDefinition variable is the TaskDefinition object.
    Dim taskDefinition
    ' The flags parameter is 0 because it is not supported.
    Set taskDefinition = service.NewTask(0)

    '********************************************************
    ' Define information about the task.

    ' Set the registration info for the task by
    ' creating the RegistrationInfo object.
    Dim regInfo
    Set regInfo = taskDefinition.RegistrationInfo
    regInfo.Description = "Start an Excel document by a specified time."
    regInfo.Author = "Author Name"

    '********************************************************
    ' Set the principal for the task
    Dim principal
    Set principal = taskDefinition.principal

    ' Set the logon type to interactive logon
    principal.LogonType = 3


    ' Set the task setting info for the Task Scheduler by
    ' creating a TaskSettings object.
    Dim settings
    Set settings = taskDefinition.settings
    settings.Enabled = True
    settings.StartWhenAvailable = True
    settings.Hidden = False

    '********************************************************
    ' Create a time-based trigger.
    Dim triggers
    Set triggers = taskDefinition.triggers

    Dim trigger
    Set trigger = triggers.Create(TriggerTypeTime)

    ' Trigger variables that define when the trigger is active.
    Dim startTime, endTime

    Dim time
    time = DateAdd("s", 30, Now)  'start time = 30 seconds from now
    startTime = XmlTime(time)

    time = DateAdd("n", 5, Now) 'end time = 5 minutes from now
    endTime = XmlTime(time)

    WScript.Echo "startTime :" & startTime
    WScript.Echo "endTime :" & endTime

    trigger.StartBoundary = startTime
    trigger.EndBoundary = endTime
    trigger.ExecutionTimeLimit = "PT5M"    'Five minutes
    trigger.ID = "TimeTriggerId"
    trigger.Enabled = True

    '***********************************************************
    ' Create the action for the task to execute.

    ' Add an action to the task to run notepad.exe.
    Dim Action
    Set Action = taskDefinition.Actions.Create(ActionTypeExec)
    Action.Path = Chr(34) & Application.Path & "\EXCEL.EXE"" " & """C:\This\is\the\path\to your\file.xlsx"""

    WScript.Echo "Task definition created. About to submit the task..."

    '***********************************************************
    ' Register (create) the task.

    Call rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition( _
        "Test TimeTrigger", taskDefinition, 6, , , 3)

    WScript.Echo "Task submitted."
End Sub

'------------------------------------------------------------------
' Used to get the time for the trigger
' startBoundary and endBoundary.
' Return the time in the correct format:
' YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.
'------------------------------------------------------------------
Function XmlTime(t)
    Dim cSecond, cMinute, CHour, cDay, cMonth, cYear
    Dim tTime, tDate

    cSecond = "0" & Second(t)
    cMinute = "0" & Minute(t)
    CHour = "0" & Hour(t)
    cDay = "0" & Day(t)
    cMonth = "0" & Month(t)
    cYear = Year(t)

    tTime = Right(CHour, 2) & ":" & Right(cMinute, 2) & _
        ":" & Right(cSecond, 2)
    tDate = cYear & "-" & Right(cMonth, 2) & "-" & Right(cDay, 2)
    XmlTime = tDate & "T" & tTime
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have the rights now. I have set the time for task 2 mins now. lets hope it run successfully. i would get back to you guys once it runs successfully. Than you guys, i appreciate really. Take Care !! I be Back. I am really filled with joy because of the support you guys have provided.

Comment: You're very welcome. If you found this answer helpful, please consider accepting it, so others can benefit from it. And if you need more help, just ask :)

Comment: I am doing what you said but my task scheduler is asking me "choose app to open this file". :(

Comment: Dear Louis, I cannot join the room and talk because I need to have reputation twenty it says. I dont have it. :(

Comment: @Kaustubh Ursekar Never mind, I've updated the code. Tell me if it works now :)

Comment: I used your code. But I am currently using it in ThisWorkbook. Is that wrong? should I use it in module 1 - StandardizationReferralReports() ??

Comment: @Kaustubh Ursekar No, it's not wrong, but it's better if you put the code in a Module. I've edited my aswer to put the code into a routine. You can copy and test it.

Comment: I have edit my code and put up above in my question. Can you please check?

Comment: Can you please correct what is wrong here?

Comment: Your question has been marked as duplicate, try opening a new one and try to be as specific as possible about what's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I created a .vbs file to call my function vba then I use TASK SCHEDULER in Windows so you don't need open your excel file, just keep your pc on and it will launch automatic

```
Option Explicit

On Error Resume Next

ExcelMacroExample

Sub ExcelMacroExample() 

  Dim xlApp 
  Dim xlBook 

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyWorkbook.xls", 0, True) 
  xlApp.Run "MyMacro"
  xlApp.Quit 

  Set xlBook = Nothing 
  Set xlApp = Nothing 

  End Sub
```

If you’ve never used the Task Scheduler, it’s tucked away in your start menu at Start Menu → Windows Administrative Tools. 
On the right side of the Task Scheduler window is an Actions box. Under that box, click the button to Create Basic Task…. Go ahead and name your task, then give it a description if you’d like Click Next, and then you select your vbs file and you can give him date and time you want to run it (or you can ask him to repeat every week or every day with a time).

The .bat file code

```
cscript c:\yourVBSFile.vbs
```

Comment: Hello Bro. I used your way but the task scheduler just open the text document with .vbs file. It does not execute it :( - Please guide me what I am missing. Also when I directly try to open Excel. It opens the excel app and not myexcel  document.

Comment: @KaustubhUrsekar sry, I got up, you may be need create a .bat to call your .vbs, because Task Scheduler can't run vbs directly, I forgot this.     
and you can put this code in your .bat, and then you select this .bat in task scheduler it works. 
Code bat :cscript  c:\yourVBSFile.vbs

Comment: Can you please correct what is wrong here?